# Gridview in Modal Popup Extender- Postback Issues?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, ajax

I have a C# .Net application with a gridview within an Ajax Modal Popup (VS2008). I have the grid view set to return 10 records per page with paging enabled.

When the user clicks to change page within the gridview there is a postback which closes the modal window and then opens it again using ModalPopup.show();

Is there any way to avoid the postback of the whole page and just postback the gridview whilst keeping the modal window active? At the moment the postback of the whole page gives the impression of flicker...

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Font-Italic="True" 
     Font-Names="Times New Roman" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#82B8DE">        


    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
        onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        SelectedIndex="0" ShowHeader="False" Width="700px" ControlID="GridView1" 
        EventName="PageIndexChanging" Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Times New Roman" 
        Font-Size="Medium">
         <PagerSettings PageButtonCount="12" />
         <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" BackColor="#EFF3FB" Font-Italic="True" 
             Font-Names="Times New Roman" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#82B8DE" /> 
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" ReadOnly="True">
            <ItemStyle Width="385px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="XCoord" ReadOnly="True" ShowHeader="False" >
            <ItemStyle CssClass="Hidden" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="YCoord" ReadOnly="True" ShowHeader="False" >
            <ItemStyle CssClass="Hidden" />
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle CssClass="FooterStyle" BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" 
            ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="SelectedRowStyle" BackColor="#D1DDF1" 
            Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" 
            ForeColor="White" />

        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" Font-Italic="True" 
             Font-Names="Times New Roman" Font-Size="Medium" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

    </asp:GridView>


</asp:Panel>


<ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="dummy" 
BackgroundCssClass="ModalBackgroundGrid" BehaviorID="ModalGrid">
</ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
```

And the code behind...

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        if (!(Page.IsPostBack))
        {
            GridView1.EnableViewState = true;
            GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
            GridView1.PageSize = 10;
            GridView1.PagerSettings.Mode = PagerButtons.Numeric;
            GridView1.Visible = true;             

        }

        if (!m_bDisclaimerShown)
        {
            m_bDisclaimerShown = true;
            mpe1.Show();
            TabContainer.Visible = true;
            ScaleBar1.Visible = true;


        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ShowMsg("Error - " + ex.Message);
    }

}

protected void btnHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mpe1.Hide();
    TabContainer.Visible = true;
    ScaleBar1.Visible = true;

}

protected void cmdZoomAddress_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        if (txtPostCode.Text.Length >= 7 && OpenDB())
        {
            string strPostcode = txtPostCode.Text;
            strPostcode = strPostcode.Substring(0, 4) + strPostcode.Substring(strPostcode.Length - 3, 3);

            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCmd.Connection = m_sqlConn;
            sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "sde.dbo.sp_selAddressByPostcode";
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Postcode", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@Postcode"].Value = strPostcode;

            SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
            m_sqlDataTable = new DataTable();
            sqlAdapter.Fill(m_sqlDataTable);

            GridView1.DataSource = m_sqlDataTable;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.Visible = true;

            ModalPopupExtender1.Show();

        }

        else
        {
            ShowMsg("Error - No Postal Addresses Returned");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ShowMsg("Error - " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseDB();
    }

}

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender != null)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataSource = m_sqlDataTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();

    }
}

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow GVRow = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    int iX = (int)Convert.ToSingle(GVRow.Cells[1].Text);
    int iY = (int)Convert.ToSingle(GVRow.Cells[2].Text);
    GridView1.Visible = false;

    MoveMap(iX, iY);
}

public void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.DataItemIndex >= 0)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["style"] = "cursor:pointer";
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver", "this.style.cursor='hand';");
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()));
    }

}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{

    foreach (GridViewRow r in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (r.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(GridView1.UniqueID, "Select$" + r.RowIndex);
        }
    }

    base.Render(writer);
}
```

Comment: how locked into doing this from code-behind are you? There are some very elegant solutions to this kind of problem on the client side using javascript and jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your suggestion. I've put the gridview into a...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
<ContentTemplate>
```

The modal now stays however when I click a record in the grid view it doesn't close!

Comment: I then added a modalpopup.hide() after the protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) and a response.redirect("default.aspx") to force a post back to update my map!